# Problem of Installing DRC from source (gzmath.hh)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Original Link : [link text](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Install)

Step7: There is a problem of no gzmath.hh library.

You need to change the source code in this file.
There is a typo in this file.

drcsim/ros/atlas_msgs/gz_model_teleport.cpp

Original code is

```
#include <math/gzmath.hh>
```

should change to

```
#include <gazebo/math/gzmath.hh>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4280/problem-of-installing-drc-from-source-(gzmath.hh)/) by [SiuLam](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/483/siulam/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SiuLam](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/483/siulam/) on 2013-09-06**:
This is a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Due to gazebo [pull request 691](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/691/remove-gazebo-include-subdir-from), all gazebo include statements require a leading `gazebo/`. This would explain the problem with drcsim not compiling for you, but I would suggest to `hg pull` and `hg up`, since this has already been fixed in the drcsim default branch by [pull request 375](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/375/fix-full-path-for-include/diff).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0